# How to set NSStatusBar title from other class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

In one of my classes i setup my NSStatusBar like:

```
        statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
```

Is it possible to somehow call something like:

```
[statusItem setTitle:@"Waiting for data..."];
```

From another class? I want to change the title as a user has entered information into a preferences window that is being handled by a different class.

I tried to make a class function:

```
+(void)ChangeTitel
```

Which i called from the preferences class, it seemed to be able to call it but somehow not access the statusItem object.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the title from another class, that other class needs to have a reference to that status Item.

So what you have to do, is write a method that returns the pointer of this status item, ( its an instance variable right? ) and then call that method, to get the NSStatusItem object in the other class.

I think you are new to OOP coding, judging from your question. A class is a set of code.. sorta, if you [[Class alloc] init] you allocate some memory for the class, and create a new object of that class in it. A new instance. 
If you call something that starts with a - then you are calling an instance method, that requires you to have an instance. If you call something with a + you are calling a CLASS method, which has no instance, so no access to the instance variable of you status item.

```
- (NSStatusItem *)statusItem
{ return statusItem; }
```

Don't forget to declare this method in your header file as well, otherwise you will get a compiler warning.

Should be in the class that manages the status item.
Then in the class where you want to use the status item:

```
#import "ManagerClass.h" // on top, so we have the method declared
```

Then:

```
ManagerClass *someInstanceToIt = [[ManagerClass alloc] init];
[(NSStatusItem *)[someInstanceToIt statusItem] setTitle:@"New Title"];
```

If the instance of the manager class is an interface builder outlet, or has been created before, then you shouldn't do that first line with alloc] init]

If you need any more help, post a comment.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help :) Im still new to this.. so i implemented the - (NSStatusItem *)statusItem in my ManagerClass implementation and also into the ManagerClass header. still cant get it to change the title, must still be doing something wrong :)

Comment: @Samirah what you could do to fix that, or atleast to find out what is going wrong you could check with an IF clause whether the [someInstanceToIt statusItem] actually returns a value, if( [someInstanceToIt statusItem] ) would make sure it returns a value

Comment: ahh dident think of that, the if tells me that the statusItem is not being passed correctly

Comment: @Samarih can't really do much more at this point, I would need to take a  look at the code and the architecture

Comment: could i send you the code Antwan? desperately trying to get this to work :)

Comment: @samirah If you haven't fixed it by now, you can yes